# Spotfire: How to use trellis to show 4 elements: 3 years + set of records older than 3 years?

Tags: spotfire

Lets say I have the data about some kind of requests.
I have column determining request's creation date.
I wish to show the requestes Trellis'ed by this date but not the standard way.
I wish all the requests with creation date older than 2013-01-01 to be grouppped in one trellis graph. 
I also would like to retain the possibility to have information on both year and quarter level as it is available for typical date column.

The image below show sth similar to what I need but the Empty section comes as the last one and I need it with different label and on the left hand side rather than as it is now on the right hand side.

Any ideas ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- my suggestion is to make two visualizations. you can duplicate the one you've already created and then limit its data by editing the properties for that vis, viewing the **Data** page, and using the **Limit data using expression** field, giving an expression like `[Date Column] < "2013-01-01"`. you'd do the same on the second vis except use an expression like `[Date Column] >= "2013-01-01"`.
- the easiest way to change (Empty) to "something" is to not leave it empty :) you can create a calculated column with the expression `If([Column] is null, "Custom Empty", [Column])` and then use that on the horizontal axis. alternatively you can hide (Empty) values from a visualization by limiting the visualization by an expression like `[Column] is not null`.
- you can adjust the order which values are shown by going to the **Edit** menu and choosing **Column Properties**. choose the column, click the **Sort Order** tab, select **Custom Sort Order**, and click **Configure**.